# Apple File Sharing crashes every night at 11:37pm

Tags: network, file-sharing

I have this extremely strange and odd thing happening to me.

I have an iMac - mid 2011 model with mavericks installed. It has file sharing setup with SMB disabled so that my MacBook Pro can connect to an external drive shared via that iMac and use it as a networked time capsule essentially.

But for some weird and strange reason unknown to me, every single night, without fail, the file sharing stops responding at 11:37pm. The Mac still appears on the network, screen sharing works, but file sharing times out.

If I were to go to the file sharing settings, clicking the options button (that reveals the abilities to enable/disable AFP or SMB) takes around 20-30 seconds to load and rainbow wheels in the meantime. Same with closing the dialog.

However, a simple fix such as unchecking the file sharing option and enabling it again (and then disabling SMB again to make time machine to work) works perfectly. Networked machines have access to the file share once again and backups resume...until 24 hours later and the whole process starts again.

What the heck could be going on! I have never seen anything like this and the fact that it happens the second the clock hits 11:37 has me scratching my head to know end as to what it could be.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you have a look at the logs in Console.app yet? What of they say around the time?